# How do I use the generated jade.js from lineman-jade

Tags: node.js, angularjs, pug, linemanjs

I have just started using LinemanJS and I am using the lineman-angular-template as my starter project.

I have converted all the default .js files into .coffee and everything worked as expected.

Then I converted all the .html files into .jade, but then everything broke.

My generated jade file can be seen here -> http://pastebin.com/UAGd4ZAW

Now I have no clue on how to use the generated jade.js file in my html.

Just loading the page itself, nothing loads. I guess the templates are not found.

I tried to add the js file to the index.html, but that didn't work either.

In both cases, the browser / inspector just hands and chrome crashes.

Comment: Why don't you accept the following answer ?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for Necromancing, but if I had found that answer here - I would saved some time.

I understand it's yours github repo:
https://github.com/ksprashu/lineman-jade-template

If I understand correctly this comment:
https://github.com/linemanjs/lineman/issues/83#issuecomment-20059462

Yours route in routes.js should looks like this:

```
$routeProvider.when "/login", 
    template: JST['app/templates/login'](),
    controller: "LoginController"
```